# Delete item within owned collection using GWT RequestFactory

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, requestfactory

I have a simple 1-n relationship (Product -> Item) mapped with RF EntityProxy. So,

```
ProductProxy extends EntityProxy {
    List <ItemProxy> getItems();
    void setItems(List<ItemProxy> items);
}
```

I have also a Product Editor with a nested ListEditor for Items. Everything is working fine if I Add new a Item to product.items list or edit any of them (save successfully).

However, If I remove one Item from the ProductProxy.getItems().remove(index) and try to save that product as a whole I noticed that when the object arrives on the server side, the item I've just removed is still within the collection.

It seems to me that RF tries a lookup for the objects into the datastore (using the Locator) before injecting the new values into the service object.

I need basically to be able to remove an Item within the collection and save the new (modified) collection into the Product object.

Thanks!!

PS. I'm using Objectify Ref<> to keep that collections.

Payload before sending request:

```
 {"F":"web.app.gwt.shared.AppRequestFactory","O":[{"T":"kKv$zKrUQuvZDqvbc2XdTq6i1qU=","V":"NC4w","P":{"defaultOptions":[]},"S":"IjI5MiI=","O":"UPDATE"},{"T":"_dEu_lZqt6BooJQsjzBeHUf38EY=","V":"NC4w","S":"IjI5MCI=","O":"UPDATE"},{"T":"_dEu_lZqt6BooJQsjzBeHUf38EY=","V":"NC4w","S":"IjI4OSI=","O":"UPDATE"},{"T":"_dEu_lZqt6BooJQsjzBeHUf38EY=","V":"NC4w","S":"IjI5MSI=","O":"UPDATE"}],"I":[{"P":[{"T":"kKv$zKrUQuvZDqvbc2XdTq6i1qU=","S":"IjI5MiI="}],"O":"O4GgjqqjQkeFcxD6lGwHruEwO6U="}]}
```

Comment: Can you post the request payload?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I posted the request payload, is the any way to see it in a not minified way?

Comment: Could it be that you're trying to modify the _frozen_ proxy's list? https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7533 Or maybe it's https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6903 Anyway, the client does not _see_ any change in the "items" property value (it does not appear in the request payload)

Comment: Thanks Thomas! That in fact helped me to figure out the problem. The proxy bean workflow was not well defined:)